# Low quality mp3 files are not playing properly as expected

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media-player, audio-player

I have been using media player from last 2 months with normal mp3 files.Few days back my client gave me 16kbps converted low quality files. When I played these files through Media player class.The behaviour which I observed is mentioned below:

- (1) `mediaPlayer.getDuration()` is giving extra duration.
   For example : If it's 46 sec then duration is returned as 86 sec.
- (2) `mediaPlayer.seekTo(positionToNavigate)` is not working properly and sound position is totally different than original.

I have tried to fix above things many times with different codes but these 2 problems are still there. When I play an MP3 file without conversion like normal quality 128kbps+, the sound and the `seekTo` work normal.

I want to mention that it is necessary to use low quality MP3 because it has small size and fast downloading from server.

If the issue is encoding/compression, is there other way to compress an MP3 with 16kbps?

Comment: What's the sample rate?  Perhaps put a link to one example file for others to test or analyze?

Comment: how to check sample rate ?

Comment: sampling rate is 8000

Comment: Is there anyway to use Dropbox or some fileshare site to share the 46 sec mp3? I can't seem to work out why its duration goes from 46 to 86 (I can calculate for 92 & why, but ofcos I must be doing it wrong...). IF you can't share file then use [**mediaInfo**](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) (drag mp3 into it) and provide following details for one mp3: samplerate? bit-depth (8 or 16 bit sound)? bitrate? stereo or mono? also for same file what is `.getDuration()` saying versus mediaInfo duration? Maybe from that someone can re-create a similar file to test your issue...

Comment: Are you expecting someone to open a sound editor program to create a blank 46 sec mp3 just for your problem? Then when saving we know to put sample rate as 8000hz but what goes in boxes for **bit-depth**?, **channels**? Encoded as **Constant** or **Variable** bitrate mode (mp3 mode = CBR or VBR)? These things can affect duration when an mp3 gets de-compressed to PCM for playback. If you can't provide a testable file or give enough info to re-create a similar file, then no-one can help you.

Comment: Thanks.i will upload a sample mp3 and you can test it. i was testing it on my end. i converted in to 32kbps and it just worked with CBR. but still not working in VBR

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt0iwctj2wtzmrb/1%284%29.mp3?dl=0

Comment: above is dropbox link to 16kbps file.